# Trying to get scanf to only look at first n number(s) of the input

Tags: c, scanf

I have a program where the user enters 3 numbers and it calculates the quadratic formula. My only problem is that my program does not work the way i would like when a user enters say "1,2,3,4". What it does is calculate like normal for "1,2,3" but then tries again after for just "4". I want to tell the user they have inputted an invalid input, but not sure how.

Below is my code:

```
    printf("Please enter the coefficients a, b, c: ");
    num = scanf("%f, %f, %f", &a, &b, &c);

    if (num != 3) {
        printf("Invalid argument\n");
        break;
    }
```

How can I get it to realize that 4 characters is a bad input. (Note: it works if I enter just "1,2" or anything less)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write:

```
if ( num != 3 || getchar() != '\n' )
```

If you intend to use this code in a loop (or indeed have any other input after this) then you probably want to flush the buffer inside the `{ }` for this `if`:

```
int ch; 
while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

After accept answer

"it works if I enter just "1,2" or anything less".  Doubtful: Try entering "1,2," (added comma) - it will just sit there waiting for more input.  The solution is to read a *line* and then parse it for acceptability.

```
for (;;) {    
  printf("Please enter the coefficients a, b, c: ");
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOerror();

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%f ,%f ,%f %n", &a, &b, &c, &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') {
    // Success - Not too much, not too little, just right
    break; 
  }
}
```